# WordPress redirect to page if taxonomy is empty

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy option called "tipo_coche", **tipo_coche** contains *convertible, coupe, compacto, etc..* All created with CPT UI, some can be empty. I need an automatic reirect to page "/coches-segunda-mano-ocasion" when they do not contain elements.

I have tried with this code but without success.

```php
function custom_redirector(){
    if (isset($_GET["s"]) and $_GET["s"]=='' and !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'tipo_coche')!==false){
           header("location: ".home_url('/coches-segunda-mano-ocasion')); exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what hook are you using to call this function?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the function: `wp_safe_redirect()` like so:

```
wp_safe_redirect( $url );
exit;
```